no generateSqlDelightSchema task SQLDelight
I am using migrations for my SQLDelight KMM database. They seem to work fine, however, I would like to also verify them as described in the docs. For some reason I do not see the generateSqlDelightSchema task as described there. This is the relevant part of my gradle file:
sqldelight {
    databases {
        create("ContentHuntDatabase") {
            packageName = "com.xamoom.contenthunt.data"
            schemaOutputDirectory = file("src/commonMain/sqldelight/com/xamoom/contenthunt/data")
            deriveSchemaFromMigrations = true
            verifyMigrations = true
            generateAsync = true
        }
    }
}

Any ideas on why I do not see the task?

It seems like the SQLDelight documentation is a bit out of date.
Now, SQLDelight generates a task called generate${targetName}${databaseName}Schema. For example, mine is generateCommonMainAppDatabaseSchema.
You can see all the tasks available by running this command: gradlew tasks. In the results, search for "Sqldelight tasks" and you will find all the tasks created by SQLDelight.
